# Derivative of Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix w.r.t. to its Lower Triangular Cholesky Factor

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, covariance, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

**Setup:**

Let $k\in{}\mathbb{N}$ be a natural number, and let $\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of $k\times{}k$ matrices over the field of real numbers.

Let $X\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Let $L\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{R})$ be the lower triangular Cholesky factor of $X$, such that
$X = LL'.$

**Question:**

What is the analytical expression for the $[k(k+1)/2] \times{} [k(k+1)/2]$ Jacobian matrix

$$\frac{\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(LL')}{\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(L)'}$$

where $\mathrm{vech}(\cdot{})$ is the half-vectorization operator that stacks the lower triangular part of its square argument matrix.

Comment: Why don't just apply the product rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be familiar with the 
[Duplication ($D_k$), Elimination ($L_k$),](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices)
and [Commutation ($K_k$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) matrices used to
manipulate Kronecker-vec/vech expressions.

Since the symbol $L$ will be used for Elimination matrices, I'll be using
$X=CC^T$ as the Choleski factorization.

Start by taking the differential of the matrix relation, then apply vectorization
$$\eqalign{
 X &= CC^T \cr
\cr
dX &= dC\,C^T + C\,dC^T \cr
\cr
{\rm vec}(dX) &= (C\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dC) + (I\otimes C)\,{\rm vec}(dC^T) \cr
  &= \Big[(C\otimes I) + (I\otimes C)K_k \Big]\,{\rm vec}(dC) \cr
\cr
L_k{\rm vec}(dX)
  &= L_k\Big[(C\otimes I) + (I\otimes C)K_k \Big]\,D_k{\rm vech}(dC) \cr
{\rm vech}(dX)
  &= L_k\Big[(C\otimes I) + (I\otimes C)K_k \Big]\,D_k\,{\rm vech}(dC) \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial{\rm vech}(X)}{\partial{\rm vech}(C)}
  &= L_k\Big[(C\otimes I) + (I\otimes C)K_k \Big]\,D_k \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked up the definitions & properties of the elimination, commutation and duplication matrices and checked all the steps you made. I get the same result as you. Thanks again!

Comment: It should be noted that the $D_k$ matrix used above is not the standard Duplication matrix, but rather a Triangular Duplication matrix
$$D_\Delta = {\rm Diag}(D_kL_k)\cdot D_k$$
The difference is that $D_k$ generates the elements of a _symmetric_ matrix from ${\rm vech}(C)\,$ while $D_\Delta$ generates those of a _triangular_ matrix.