# Problem with Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix Gradient w.r.t. to its Lower Triangular Cholesky Factor

Tags: calculus, matrices, vector-analysis

I apologize if my question is duplicate, but I really need to know this. I tried to verify equation $\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}$ suggested by [Lynn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/234414/lynn) in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158399/derivative-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-w-r-t-to-its-lower-triangular/). As a simple case, I consider a 2x2 symmetric p.s.d matrix $X=CC^T$. To this end, I computed every element of $\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}$ one by one as follows (equation 1). Assuming matrix $C$ to be:
\begin{equation}
C=\begin{bmatrix} 
c_{11} & 0 \\
c_{21} & c_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
then matrix X will be:
\begin{equation}
X=\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
c_{11}^2 & c_{11}c_{12} \\
c_{11}c_{21} & c_{21}^2+c_{22}^2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$=>$

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial c_{11}^2}{\partial c_{11}} & \frac{\partial c_{11}^2}{\partial c_{21}} & \frac{\partial c_{11}^2}{\partial c_{22}} \\
\frac{\partial c_{11}c_{21}}{\partial c_{11}} & \frac{\partial c_{11}c_{21}}{\partial c_{21}} & \frac{\partial c_{11}c_{21}}{\partial c_{22}} \\
\frac{\partial (c_{21}^2+c_{22}^2)}{\partial c_{11}} & \frac{\partial (c_{21}^2+c_{22}^2)}{\partial c_{21}} & \frac{\partial (c_{21}^2+c_{22}^2)}{\partial c_{22}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 
2c_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
c_{21} & c_{11} & 0 \\
0 & 2c_{21} & 2c_{22} 
\end{bmatrix} \quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
\end{equation}

Now using equation $\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}=L[(C \otimes I)+(I \otimes C)K]D$ from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158399/derivative-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-w-r-t-to-its-lower-triangular/), the following result is obtained:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
c_{21} & 0 & c_{22} & 0 \\
0 & c_{21} & 0 & c_{22}
\end{bmatrix} + \\
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c_{21} & c_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c_{11} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c_{21} & c_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \right\}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} =>
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2c_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
c_{21} & c_{11}+c_{22} & 0 \\
0 & 2c_{21} & 2c_{22}
\end{bmatrix} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (2)
\end{equation}
As can be seen, value at cell (2,2) of the Jacobian matrix in equation 2 is different from the value at the same cell in equation 1. Please correct me if I am making a mistake here. But if I'm right, then does it mean that $\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}$ equation suggested by Lynn is wrong? If that's the case, can anyone give the correct answer, please? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution myself. The problem with the [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158399/derivative-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-w-r-t-to-its-lower-triangular?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggested by Lynn is that we can't use duplication matrix to convert $vec(dC)$ to $D_k vech(dC)$ because matrix $dC$ is lower triangular and not **symmetric**. Recall that, for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $vec(A)=D_n vech(A)$ only when $A$ is symmetric [[see here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices).

The correct answer for $\frac{\partial vech(X)}{\partial vech(C)}$ is available in section 10.5.4 of book [Handbook of Matrices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471970158):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial vech(CC^T)}{\partial vech(C)^T} = 2D_k^+(C \otimes I_k)L^T_k \quad (1)
\end{equation}

In the equation above $D_k^+ = (D_k^T D_k)^{-1} D_k^T$ is Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of duplication matrix [[see here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

In the mentioned book, it is said that proof for equation (1) is available in book [Linear Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0852642997). Unfortunately, I don't have access to that book and I have failed to write the proof for equation (1) myself. So I appreciate if anyone can come up with the proof for equation (1).

Comment: +1  Another way to fix Lynn's formula is to keep the standard Elimination matrix $L_k$, but replace the standard Duplication matrix $D_k$ with the Triangular Duplication matrix
$$D_\Delta = {\rm Diag}(D_kL_k)\cdot D_k$$
The difference is that $D_k$ generates the elements of a _symmetric_ matrix from ${\rm vech}(C)\,$ while $D_\Delta$ generates those of a _triangular_ matrix.