# Derivative of Quadratic Form of Cholesky Factor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix and let $\mathbf{L}$ be its lower Cholesky factor. Furthermore, let $\mathbf{D}$ be a diagonal matrix.

What is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \text{vech} (\mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^\top)}{\partial \text{vech}(\mathbf{\Sigma})^\top} \quad ?
\end{align}
$$

Probably [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150427/the-derivative-of-the-cholesky-factor) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158399/derivative-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-w-r-t-to-its-lower-triangular) question is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the chain rule,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \text{vech} (\mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^\top)}{\partial \text{vech}(\mathbf{\Sigma})^\top} &= \frac{\partial \text{vech} (\mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^\top)}{\partial \text{vech}(\mathbf{L})^\top} \frac{\partial \text{vech} (\mathbf{L})}{\partial \text{vech}(\mathbf{\Sigma})^\top} \\
&= \mathbf{G}^{+} \left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \otimes \mathbf{I} \right) \mathbf{F}^{\top} \left( \mathbf{G}^{+} \left(\mathbf{L} \otimes \mathbf{I}\right) \mathbf{F}^{\top} \right)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

To see this, let $\mathbf{G}$ be the duplication matrix, $\mathbf{G}^{+}$ its Moore-Penrose inverse, $\mathbf{F}$ the canonical elimination matrix (which consists of 0's and 1's only) and $\mathbf{K}$ the commutation matrix. Then
$$
 \begin{align}
  \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vech}\left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) &= \mathbf{G}^{+} \, \, \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vec} \left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\
  &=  \mathbf{G}^{+} \left( \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) + \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \right) \\
  &=  \mathbf{G}^{+}\left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{K}_{pp}\right) \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\  
  &=  \mathbf{G}^{+} \left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{K}_{pp}\right) \left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \otimes \mathbf{I} \right) \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \right) \\  
  &=  2 \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathbf{G} \mathbf{G}^{+} \left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \otimes \mathbf{I} \right) \mathbf{F}^{\top} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vech}\left( \mathbf{L} \right) \\
&=  2 \mathbf{G}^{+} \left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \otimes \mathbf{I} \right) \mathbf{F}^{\top} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vech}\left( \mathbf{L} \right),
 \end{align}
$$
and
$$
 \begin{align}
  \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vech}\left( \mathbf{\Sigma} \right) 
  &= \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\
  &= \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) + \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathbf{L} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\
  &= \mathbf{G}^{+} \left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{K}_{pp}\right) \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\
  &= \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathbf{G} \mathbf{G}^{+} \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}^{\top} \right) \\ 
  &= 2 \mathbf{G}^{+} \left(\mathbf{L} \otimes \mathbf{I}\right) \mathrm{vec}\left( \mathrm{d} \mathbf{L} \right) \\
  &= 2 \mathbf{G}^{+} \left(\mathbf{L} \otimes \mathbf{I}\right) \mathbf{F}^{\top} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vech}\left( \mathbf{L} \right).
 \end{align} 
$$

Comment: $+\tt1\;$ You can eliminate one of the matrix variables by replacing $\,F\,$ with $\,G^+\;$

Comment: @greg, actually you have to keep in mind that $\mathbf{L}$ is a lower triangular matrix, which means that $\mathrm{vec} (\mathbf{L}) = \mathbf{F}^\top \mathrm{vech} (\mathbf{L})$. So we cannot replace $\mathbf{F}^\top$.

Comment: Agreed. But $F^T$ isn't technically a duplication or elimination matrix. Instead it's a way to create a _triangular_ matrix from a vector of the appropriate length. I think [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/167719)  (which you've basically re-derived) uses a really good notation for this distinction.

Comment: @greg True, $\mathbf{F}^\top$ just maps the $\mathrm{vech}$ of a lower triangular into its $\mathrm{vec}$. The answer you are referring to is actually a re-derivation itself of a result by [Lütkepohl (1989)](http://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(89)90059-6), Lemma 1.

Comment: @stollenm Do you really need this computation ? I imagine you are computing analytically some gradient of a scalar-valued function $\phi$ involving the matrix $\mathbf{L} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{L}^T$ and you are interested in the gradient $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}}$ at some point. There are other tools than vech to do this. If I am correct ,can you give us the whole picture ?